# not working viewstate in asp

Tags: c#, asp.net, viewstate

In my ASP.NET Web Application, I have a "Next" button control.  Each time I click this button, I want the value of `ViewState["QNO"]` to increase by 1.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            int qno = Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["QNO"]);
            if (ViewState["QNO"] == null)
            {
                ViewState["QNO"] = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                ViewState["QNO"] = qno++;
            }
        }
```

Code for click event on button:

```
protected void btnNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(str);
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from QSet where QID='" + ViewState["QNO"] + "'", con);
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (dr.Read())
        {
            lblNo.Text = "(" + dr.GetValue(0).ToString() + ")";
            lblQues.Text = dr.GetValue(1).ToString();
            Qoptions.Items.Add(dr.GetValue(2).ToString());
            Qoptions.Items.Add(dr.GetValue(3).ToString());
            Qoptions.Items.Add(dr.GetValue(4).ToString());
            Qoptions.Items.Add(dr.GetValue(5).ToString());
        }

        con.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Give us more detail... I'm assuming that it's NOT increasing by 1?

Comment: sir , just i want every time , when i click on next button, value of viewstate should be increase by 1, so that in my sqlcommand i can get a new incremented value for QID.
like when page load then QID should be 1 , then i click on next then QID should be 2 and so on

Comment: Amit, check my answer.

Comment: What is QNO ? Is this a label or hiddenfiled or something else??

Comment: It's just an arbitrary `ViewState` variable.

Comment: it is viewstate variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code for Page Load as this:

```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
                ViewState["QNO"] = 1;
        }
        else
         {
             ViewState["QNO"] = Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["QNO"]) +1;
         }
}
```

Comment: thank you sir. it is working fine. one more thing , can tell me please how can i remove all the previous radiobuttonlist item whenever new QNO is genereted.

Comment: For the appropriate answer you will need to post your aspx as well as cs code. But if you exactly want what you say then you can do it as YourRadioButtonList.Items.Clear().

Comment: you got my point. i just want to remove all the items. this method working .
thanks a lot sir

Answer (score 1):

I believe a server side button click causes a `PostBack`.  In your code, you have `if (!IsPostBack)` then increment by 1.  Change to `if (IsPostBack)` perhaps.

Comment: but still value of viewstate did not change, it is 1, but i want on every click it should increment by 1,
i changed it to 
if(IsPostBack)

Answer (score 1):

code inside `if (!IsPostBack)` will only be hit on initial load.

change load code to

```
if (IsPostBack)
    {
        if (ViewState["QNO"] == null)
        {
            ViewState["QNO"] = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            int qno = Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["QNO"]);
            ViewState["QNO"] = qno++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yep, exactly what I said. :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the assignment of the increment operator. Also, I made few corrections.

```
    public void IncrementQNO()
    {
        if (ViewState["QNO"] == null)
        {
            ViewState["QNO"] = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            int qno = Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["QNO"]);
            ViewState["QNO"] = ++qno;
        }
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       IncrementQNO();
    }
```

Just tested this and it works fine.

Answer (score -1):

In your page_load, this line will fail right away:

```
int qno = Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["QNO"]);
```

The code is not running in a postback, so anything you pull out of viewstate will, by definition, be null.

You need another code path to initialize "QNO" with 0 if not in postback.